# Jquery Daily Timer Failing

Tags: jquery, timer

I am using this jQuery code to display the left left until 10am locally.

Between 10am and 14:00pm it removes some images.

Then after 14:00 it should display time left until 10am. It also adds an offset to account for weekends.

It works brilliantly most of the time, however it seems after 14:00 it goes way over the time...

Can anyone see why this is failing, I've been looking at it for to long... now I'm just confussed! Please help!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// 24 hour based
var targetTime = 1000;
var targetHour = 10;
var openingTime = 1400;
var openingHour = 14;

var currentTime = new Date();

// sun 0 mon 1 ... fri 5 sat 6
var currentDay = currentTime.getDay();

var offset = 24;
// friday
if (currentDay === 5) {
    offset = 60;
} // saturday
else if (currentDay === 6) {
    offset = 48;
}

var the_current_time = ''+ currentTime.getHours() + '' + currentTime.getMinutes() + '';



if( the_current_time > targetTime && the_current_time < openingTime ) {

    var time_hours = (openingHour + offset) - currentTime.getHours() - 1;
    var time_min = 60 - currentTime.getMinutes();
    var time_seconds = 60 - currentTime.getSeconds();

    $('#hours_left').append(time_hours, ':',time_min < 10 ? "0" : "" , time_min , ':' , time_seconds < 10 ? "0" : "" , time_seconds);
    $('#watch_image').attr('src','http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0085/1702/t/1/assets/closed-until-icon.png');
    $('#time-left-banner').css('width','275px');
    $('.add-to-button').css('display','none');
    $('#purchase').css('display','none');


}
else if( the_current_time > targetTime && the_current_time > openingTime ) {

     var time_hours = (targetHour + offset) - currentTime.getHours() - 1;
     var time_min = 60 - currentTime.getMinutes();
     var time_seconds = 60 - currentTime.getSeconds();

    $('#hours_left').append(time_hours, ':',time_min < 10 ? "0" : "" , time_min , ':' , time_seconds < 10 ? "0" : "" , time_seconds);

}

else {
 var time_hours = (targetHour + offset) - currentTime.getHours() - 1;
 var time_min = 60 - currentTime.getMinutes();
 var time_seconds = 60 - currentTime.getSeconds();

 $('#hours_left').append(time_hours, ':',time_min < 10 ? "0" : "" , time_min , ':' , time_seconds < 10 ? "0" : "" , time_seconds);  
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would simplify the code a bit. The three `var` calculation in all three branches seem to be the same. So is the updating of `#hours_left`. You should be able to factor them out of the `if`. This will also reduce the number of if branches from 3 to 1 - if I am not missing something.

As for the problem, I would look at `the_current_time`. You are not zero padding the minutes, so 10:05 will become 105, or 1:05. I can't see how this would cause any dramas, as the calculations do not depend on this value, but it will change the if branch you will take.

---

Ah, I missed the `time_hours` calculation difference in the first branch of `if`. It uses `opening_hours` instead of `target_hours`. This explains why a bad `the_current_time` will make a difference on the reported value.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response vhallac, dont I need that to calculate the time until it reopens?

Comment: You can safely ignore my comments about refactoring. I mentioned it, because you can shrink the function by about 10-15 lines, and less lines of code hides less bugs. You only need to zero pad the minutes in `the_current_time` (or calculate it as `hours*100+minutes`).